# Windows 8 dropping wifi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

I have a laptop where I just installed Windows 8, and since that moment the wireless connection is making me crazy. Most of the times it loses the connection to the network, a few times it just loses internet connectivity but it's still connected to the network. In either case, the only way of getting the connection back is to disable and enable the wireless adapter (I do it with an actual hardware switch that the laptop has).

This problem only happens with Windows 8. I have a dual boot with Windows 7 and everything is fine. Also, any other device (phones, tablets, other computers...) connected to the same network has this problem.

I've uninstalled the wireless adapter driver to get the latest one, but still the same problem.

Is there anything else I can do? Apart from dropping Windows 8, of course...

**EDIT**

Laptop: Sony Vaio F Series (VPCF226FM)
Wireless adapter: Intel Centrino Wireless-N 6150
All Windows 8 updates installed
Most recent laptop manufacturer drivers installed

Comment: it might help massively to give information on what your laptop actually is, and what the wireless adaptor is

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: you're right! there you go

Answer (score 1):

There have been many driver issues with Windows 8 and wireless.  Make sure you check to see if there is any driver updates from any of the following (unfortunately, Windows does not have an easy way to do this in all cases):

- Windows update (many times driver updates are listed under "Optional" updates)
- Laptop manufacturer (i.e. Lenovo, Dell, HP, etc)
- Wireless adapter manufacturer (i.e. Linksys, Netgear, etc)
- Wireless chipset manufacturer (i.e. Intel, Ralink/MediaTek, etc)

Additionally, there may be a firmware update for your router/access point/gateway device.  This may help as well.

**Edit (since you provided new details)**
For Intel drivers, make sure you update them off the Intel site.  They provide a driver update utliity now that will help you locate the correct drivers:
http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect